# How to make Thread/Job wait until the previous Job is finished and thereafter resume it on some Notification

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I have a camel route which will perform an update on a given ID.

For a single request everything works fine, say **If I have multiple request with same ID say 10, Then I want single request to execute at a time**.

or making wait other request with same ID, meanwhile if I have request with other ID that can be processed without waiting say 12.

For this I have created an Additional Route in my Camel Context "addRequestToPool" this will route all the request coming to camel "updateTicket" to 1 place and from there 1 by 1 processing should be performed.

**I want to implement something like below** :

When a request comes to "synchronizeRequests" method it should check if there is already existing job with docketId if there is make it wait till the old process is finished(say 10). if there is no such id (say 12) continue processing.

Once Old process is Finished it should tell other jobs with same ID waiting that 1 of them can resume there work from where they have waiting so that response should be sent.

Request collection is done from route "addRequestToPool" once request comes it will create a thread for each request and call synchronize method. Inside synchronize method "RequestSynchronization" I want to perform check operation for existing Job with ID if it exist wait for notification from previous if not return response and continue with processing.

Once the Job is finished at end using route "removeRequestFromPool" the current id of the job is removed and new job among the group (same ID) should be notified to continue.

I would like to know How shall I implement the above scenario or any other appropriate approach if any?

Below is sample piece of code for the reference,

Camel Route :

```
from("direct:updateTicket")
    .to("direct:addRequestToPool")
    .to("direct:getDetailForTicket")
    .to("direct:updateDetailForTroubleTicket")
    .to("direct:getDetailForTicket")
    .to("direct:removeRequestFromPool")
    .to("direct:endRoute");
```

API Call :

```
public class TicketRequestManagement {

    public SimpleActionResponse addRequestToPool(int docketNo) throws InterruptedException {

        SimpleActionResponse response = new SimpleActionResponse();

        RequestSynchronization requestSynchronization = new RequestSynchronization(docketNo);
        Thread thread = new Thread(requestSynchronization);
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Synchronization method :

```
public class RequestSynchronization implements Runnable {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestSynchronization.class);

    private int docketNo;

    public RequestSynchronization(int docketNo) {
        super();
        this.docketNo = docketNo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronizeRequests(docketNo);
    }

    public synchronized static void synchronizeRequests(int docketNo) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I was thinking of adding docketId to static data structure (Set) and Checking if there exist Id wait (How shall I perform this wait ?) once the process is finished remove ID from set and Notify waiting process to resume from there (How shall I perform this notify to same ID ?).

Let me know if any clarity needed.

PS : I am not looking for sleep, this is just for performing synchronization test.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with _apache-camel_ but nonetheless wanted to make you aware of the JDK's concurrency utilities. See package [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and also the [tech guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/index.html) and finally the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Of-course these are not the only available references. Google for _java concurrency utilities_.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: **go asynchronous**. Use for example JMS (not directly but with [Camels excellent JMS support](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html)) to **decouple requests and processing of them**. This way you can control the whole threading stuff simply with the consumer count.

In your case this would be

- addRequestToPool puts the request on a JMS queue
- a JMS consumer consumes requests from the queue and processes them
- Use **[message groups](https://activemq.apache.org/message-groups) to synchronize requests** with the same ID
- Use the **consumer count** to make sure other IDs are processed in parallel and to scale up (you write 0 lines of code for threading stuff)
- The clients can still send update requests even if the processing component(s) are down for maintenance

Message groups are a JMS broker feature (at least ActiveMQ). You set your ID as `JMSXGroupID` and the broker makes sure that **all messages with the same ID are processed by the same consumer**. If you got 5 consumers and you receive 10 messages with the same ID, 1 consumer does all the work. As soon as a message with another ID arrives, another consumer processes it in parallel.

It is up to you if you build one big JMS component that does all processing or if you build multiple components that pass on the message through multiple queues along your processing workflow.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, don't start a `Thread` manually, that's what `ExecutorService`s are for.

Secondly, I'd suggest you maintain the started synchronizations in a `Map<Integer, Future<>>` so you can check if something is already running for that id.

A rough draft would be

```
class TicketRequestService {
    private Map<Integer, Future<?>> runningRequests = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public void synchronizeRequest(int docketId) {
        // get the running Future if present, otherwise...
        Future<?> future = runningRequests.computeIfAbsent(docketId,
            // ...create a new one
            id-> executor.submit(() -> {
                RequestSynchronization.synchronizeRequests(id));
                // remove future from map after sync is finished
                runningRequests.remove(docketId);
            });
        future.get(); // wait until finished; this throws Exceptions, you need to handle them
        return new SimpleActionResponse();
   }
}
```